# What type of instruction set is this?

Tags: binary, operating-system, opcode

In a class I am currently taking (Operating Systems), we needed to convert hexadecimal to binary and then split the binary into it's respective parts to get the Opcodes and likewise.

Here is an example of the process

```
0x4B010000
01001011000000010000000000000000
0000000000000000 001011 0000 0001
0000 MOVI 1 0
0000 MOVI R1 0

0x4C060001
01001100000001100000000000000001
0000000000000001 001100 0000 0110
0001 ADDI 6 0
0001 ADDI R6 0

0x10658000
00010000011001011000000000000000
000000000000 010000 0110 0101 1000
0000 SLT 8 6 5
0000 SLT R8 R6 R5

0x56810018
01010110100000010000000000011000
0000000000011000 010110 1000 0001
0018 BNE 1 8
0018 BNE R1 8
```

I have provided the GitHub that contains the files stating the instruction set and the instruction format, plus all the data values.

https://github.com/DavidClifford-Pro/InstructionsFormat

The instructions say to decode it like I have, and then to execute it.  I just don't understand the instructions and how it's supposed to be executed.  I believe it's all been decoded correctly.

EDIT:
The the instruction list is part of the project (the first line - the hex codes), we were given these codes to decode and then execute.

Comment: Sounds like a programming project. You need to decode the instructions and then simulate the behavior of the instructions, is my guess. Create variables representing registers, perform operations on them, etc.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the instructions document that it links to has been removed.  The question is now unanswerable.